# Зависимое слово при непереходном глаголе

Tags: глаголы

Переходные глаголы: зависимое слово - сущ. или мест. в форме В.п. без предлога (Люблю тебя).

Непереходные: зависимое слово - обстоятельство (это понятно) и опять дополнение.

В учебнике Бабайцевой дан такой пример:

> Мы прожили зиму в деревне (где зима
> является обстоятельством, а прожили -
> непереходный глагол).

Почему зима - в данном случае обстоятельство? Рассуждать так: что зима - это не предмет?

Comment: @lingvo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Глагол "прожить" является переходным (дополнение со значением времени). См. здесь:  [Семантические свойства переходных / непереходных глаголов](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=518.gcudpr-zJDDW2uEvPpBhO-WP1dagrwkCtwGrv6o8WPSvHrXOOAK-mCrdZcOWFBy3TeOod1_3_AK1je5F0-SZIvzUxfefqLiEdAMHhLl4h1PZbdeQTZG3ybhrsOqjiFcd5rH_JNFIb9STyGyMXrdIdroFFOP5esHkj8GK_xfegEeSA0xcl7dGd0f6-eYUp1FdUenBAEui64Sbr2FkN-L8MNMLyq4zikQihhO3A23PvkusXJJqoia2DDA6_3pABwVQxhBOsjXqcxaVFA3pn3D41CXrVU88wJQThl0MDXLAGd64x_3uosYR3oT-e-wnx6D-N7p7jRdjCBHL_Ow-iJFuWnvy-SKY0Z8xSfzgGuLXmKE.e4101fc5f238f9481826123fe8b6b05de79038ad&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xuhyw5P1wAdC5B4OoApALaNVEl9yvCQUYMKUNJzLv5yYp_f0QWcfguoEdHuHSy-uVKj_61tMM9LLuySV2S8ZwhlOQE0U0Apb7he3sH2RqBI5AYiP6wLgm40QEeYyOXs8I0QnsYNFVWkhFOFUId500Sgf2DQWOUm86YXnp4RpAfqOxva_76iG4skAct526FK9nQt_7PHBWbwMplsejSHjRft8YhLvDu2GfM&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxc1RoUHlrbWJJT05OMGtCaGV0Q0laSnZDT3I3Mmk0a2pnSXFJbkNFQ1dKVlNGLU4tWUFMWDJKZnE4d2lhUG9odHhXLURJelFweGlCbTRFNzlEMTMyR1NuRzBnTXFnbUFRWE1uNGhaazV4RzM1SEYxTlRkQzFZT21JZEZhbk9JTmNfOG95TzVBN2NpOHdLYmlOSWVYUThENGpWVF9uYWRQcmZhRWhIbzczTW01T0lvekpCVlZJYm1RSzFzMjNsenBmTVFHT0FrV0pzb0VFbVZUT04xWDJHVDR5SXJSUWJjWEFjTnM4eGhGT2NkZw&b64e=2&sign=fdc290aad30e25f559f2780221eab6f9&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1416843398039&mc=5.251369255313772)

Comment: А в учебнике - непереходный!  Как это понимать...

Comment: Назовите, пожалуйста, учебник. Если это обстоятельство, то на какой вопрос оно отвечает? Здесь сама приставка свидетельствует о переходности. И еще: если можно, приведите, пожалуйста, объяснение из этого учебника.

Answer (score 2):

Бабайцева рассуждает так: Мы прожили (как долго?) зиму в деревне.  зима - обстоятельство времени, а прожили - непереходный глагол.

Прожить - глагол особенный, о нём всегда шли споры, и раньше многие учёные считали его непереходным, кроме употребления в значении "истратить"- он прожил все свои деньги - здесь действие прямо переходит на предмет, а жить-прожить (долго, зиму, две зимы, всю жизнь, в течение года) - действие сродни состоянию, такие глаголы считались непереходными.

Современная лингвистика утверждает, что прожил (что? как долго?) всю свою жизнь - переходный, а жизнь - прямое дополнение, но Бабайцева имеет своё мнение: основное значение-значение времени, значит, обстоятельство. У неё своё мнение и на морфемику. Оно расходится с другими, но часто права бывает она, по крайней мере в вузах её мнение берут во внимание и о нём говорят. Может, она более консервативна. Язык меняется. Мы сейчас даже явно непереходный глагол "уйти" употребляем как переходный: Не я ушёл - меня ушли. Она это не воспринимает за норму, считает разговорным вариантом, а все остальные считают стилистическим средством литературного языка.

Comment: Признаться честно, выражение " меня ушли" слышу впервые.Людмила,  скажите, пожалуйста, где-нибудь зафиксировано такое выражение как разговорное? В выражении " мы прожили зиму" выражается не само время, а факт, который выражается именем сущ. в винительном падеже. В ссылке , которую я предоставил( Русская корпусная грамматика), четко разъясняется переходность-непереходность глаголов.

Comment: Серж, это выражение известно повсеместно. Это эрратив, поэтому он может пока и не присутствовать в учебниках, но он очень жизненный.   
(+)  
Коли уж оставил коммент.
Я по сути всего ответа полностью согласен с Людмилой. Глагол "прожить" - хитрый. Можно и так и эдак трактовать, все зависит от выбранной версии "святого писания", коему автор поклоняется. Т.е. ***модели*** грамматики. 
Что касается ваших источников, то это проблема разницы подходов. Я обычно стараюсь избегать споров о том, кто из авторитетов прав, если все упирается в борьбу школ, тем более - в банальную терминологию.

Comment: Определяющим для классификации (согласно этому материалу) является способность не просто соседствовать с существительным в винительном падеже, а присоединять дополнение в виде такого существительного. Дополнение - элемент законченного предожения, а не пары "глагол-существительное", и в данной фразе имеется обстоятельство времени, которое нельзя трактовать одновременно как нечто другое. Даже если этот глагол отнести к переходным (в переносном смысле можно "проживать деньги"), это останется условностью - он не трансформирует обстоятельство в дополнение (фактом принятия классификации глаголов ).

Comment: (продолжение) Для сравнения можно построить аналогичную фразу с явно непереходным глаголом "жить". "Эту зиму мы жили в деревне". Внешне она отличается только выбором глагола (по классификации он непереходный - нельзя даже "жить деньги"), а зима остаётся в винительном падеже. Но обстоятельство времени (которое здесь уже не поставить под сомнение идеей "переходности глагола") сохраняет фразе тот же смысл (прожитый отрезок времени), следовательно, играет в ней ту же роль (т. е. обстоятельства), что и в исходной.

Comment: Alex_ander, очень много слов, я не понял сути. Вы возражаете Людмиле? В чем конкретно? Или просто пересказываете один из многих учебников?  
Почему вы считаете, что "определяющим"(sic!) является именно способность (спостобность - м.р.?) присоединять что-то? Что вообще в вашем понимании этот термин значит? И чем плоха моя трактовка, что суть не в присоединении, а в способности образовывать страдательные причастия?

Comment: Серж,"меня ушли" указано как разговорное значение во всех толковых словарях,  посмотрите у Ефремовой, Кузнецова, как пример к 3 значению у Ожегова.

Comment: Людмила, к третьему значению у Ожегова я нашел только это: Не сам ушёл, а «его ушли(об уволенном; шутл.). И то, как видите, с пом. шутл. Другое дело с предлогом, напр.: от меня ушли. Такое употребление, конечно, слышал.

Comment: Нет, я в основном поддерживаю Людмилу и, вероятно, расхожусь с Сержем, который, говоря о переходности глагола, вероятно, имеет в виду, что из неё следует необходимость отнести здесь "зиму" к дополнению. "Определяющим для классификации" я называю основной признак, которым (согласно материалу по ссылке) должен обладать глагол для причисления его к переходным. Я не оцениваю правильность приведенных там определений (возможно, ваше вернее), а исхожу из того, как там принято. Для меня любая классификация - условность, направленная на упрощение и единообразие.

Comment: @behemothus Чтобы окончательно запутать поиск между обстоятельством и прямым дополнением, можно глагол "прожить" заменить явно переходным "провести" (провели зиму), который невозможно употребить без дополнения - тогда обстоятельство времени будет не выделить (его место занято). Это к вопросу об условности всех методов расчленения речи и классификаций.

Answer (score 0):

По циркуляру, переходный глагол - такой, который (обязательное требование) способен присоединять к себе дополнение в виде существительного в винительном падеже. В данной фразе такая "способность" не проявляется - по семантической причине, поскольку "зиму" здесь - обстоятельство времени (какой период, сколько времени прожили, с какого по какое время?). Эта причина лежит в той же плоскости (семантической), что и "способность присоединять дополнения", и здесь она попросту действует сильнее гипотетических "присоединительных" свойств глагола. Каков глагол по формальной классификации, не имеет для смысла этой фразы никакого значения. Г-жа Бабайцева права как минимум в том, что "зиму" - обстоятельство, а не дополнение.
P.S. (шутка) Попалось на глаза: (вопрос) отвечен; а "отвечать" - переходный глагол? :)

Comment: Мне кажется, сомнений по поводу переходности-непереходности глагола "отвечать"" не должны быть. Он требует дополнения в косвенном падеже.

Comment: Ответил обоим в тексте ответа.  
Для коммента многовато будет.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Alex_ander](/users/4309/alex_ander)](/users/4309/alex_ander), не всякий циркуляр раскрывает суть проблемы. На самом деле "циркулярное" определение категории переходности - не более чем (почти) универсальный *признак* преходности. Суть же введения в русский язык такой категории в том, что переходные глаголы обычно легко образуют страдательные причастия, непереходные активно этому сопротивляются. Без этого введение "переходности" не имело бы никакого смысла (ну если еще и не залезать глубоко в дебри общего языкознания "агенса и пациенса", что, конечно, совершенно не обязательно делать среднему школьнику). Так что не живите по циркулярам.

Переходность, как следует из названия, означает, что действие производителя (агенса) *переходит* на объект (пациенс), который таким образом это действие "принимает".

(+)

Серж, если я правильно понял разговоры по поводу "отвечать", то вопрос в том, насколько нормативны конструкции типа "отвечать урок". Есть в них что-то "не совсем русское". Хотя сейчас активно употребляются, несмотря на это ощущение неправильности. Отсюда и общие сомнения в переходности глагола "отвечать".

Comment: @behemothus, глагол "отвечать" несмотря на активность употребления еще не зафиксирован в этом значении. Но если это значение попадет в словарь( что очень вероятно), то, на мой, придется отнести этот глагол к т.н. лабильным.

Comment: "Отвечать урок"... я даже не вспомнил, что так говорят, но это едва ли не единственное сложившееся сочетание. А "отвечать вопрос" для меня звучит так же странно, как "гулять собаку" или "голосовать закон". Сочувствую составителям классификаций.