# Использование причастия «отвечен»

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, стилистика, причастия

Неоднократно сталкивался с использованием слова *отвечен* в контекстах типа *Ваш звонок будет **отвечен** в течение двух минут*.

Как можно охарактеризовать это краткое причастие со стилистической точки зрения? Может ли оно стилистически верно использоваться вообще?

Comment: Вот еще пример. В меню мобильного телефона: "Неотвеченные звонки". Какую адекватную замену можно предложить? Да и нужно ли?

Comment: @М_Г звонки без ответа?

Comment: Да, так лучше. Но есть там еще "отвеченные звонки". Как тут быть?

Comment: @М_Г по классике? :) «принятые звонки»

Comment: Да, спасибо. Просто я так привык к "отвеченным" и "неотвеченным", что мне стало казаться, что им нет достойной замены.

Comment: Впрочем, принятые звонки — тоже спорно, на звонки отвечают, а вызовы принимают. Может  корректней "принятые и непринятые вызовы"? Да и английское call — скорее вызов, чем звонок.

Comment: @М_Г ну почему же, английское (phone) call как раз переводится как звонок (впрочем, и как вызов в значении звонка тоже). Мне непонятно, что не так со звонком.

Comment: В английском есть звонок (звук) — *ring* , a *call* — это  зов, вызов, а в современном мире - именно телефонный звонок, то есть  вызов к телефону, а не звон. А в русском словаре звонок - звуковой сигнал или (разг) телефонный разговор. Ни то, ни другое не сочетается с "принятый" .

Comment: @М_Г ну, а как же метонимия? По-вашему, принять/отклонить звонок нельзя, а вызов — можно?

Comment: @М_Г по-английски phone call — именно телефонный разговор, то есть звонок.

Comment: Метонимия хороша для художественной литературы

Comment: @М_Г ох, как вы ошибаетесь!

Comment: @М_Г скажите, давно ли вы съедали тарелку супа?

Comment: На мой взгляд, тарелка - мера объема, тарелка супа — это как литр супа.

Comment: @М_Г вы правы, но ведь я не об этом: "Съесть три тарелки" – очень бытовая метонимия.

Comment: `В меню мобильного телефона: "Неотвеченные звонки". Какую адекватную замену можно предложить?` - пропущенные вызовы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форма **ненормированная.**

1) **Парадигма Зализняка** вообще не содержит формы страдательных причастий.https://slovar.cc/rus/zaliznyak/1515728.html

2) В толковом словаре указано **переходное значение** глагола в сочетании ***ответить урок***. Например: Я должен был просиживать ночи, чтобы **ответить урок** так же свободно, как ты. [Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана (1938-1944)]

Гоголь мог беспрепятственно лениться и действительно ленился, не обращая внимания на такие мелкие неприятности, как плохая отметка в журнале, наказание без обеда или без чая, стояние в углу **за дурно отвеченный урок.** [А. Н. Анненская. Гоголь. Его жизнь и литературная деятельность (1895)]

Однако это значение в современном языке используется мало.

3) **Ответить на звонок** ― здесь только непереходное значение глагола, образование страдательного причастия невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

В лучшем случае это *жаргонизм*, удобный данной службе телефонной разборчивостью или лаконичностью. Он аналогичен жаргонному использованию *непереходного* глагола в качестве *переходного*, известному из парламентской практики: "**голосовать закон**" - что грамматически эквивалентно "гулянию собак". Иногда в разговорной речи встречается "*отвечать вопрос* (из экзам. билета)", но и это явно "сниженный" стиль.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Скажите, пожалуйста, не известны ли вам статьи на эту тему?

Comment: Нет, не попадалось. Где-то в комментариях с год назад обсуждалось "отвечать вопрос", но сейчас не найти.

Comment: _Alex_ander: "...но сейчас не найти."_ === Это? -- https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42674/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5/42747#42747

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду более позднее обсуждение, там называлось исключение "отвечать урок", которого я сейчас не вспомнил.

Answer (score 1):

Круг будет очерчен.

Успех будет отмечен.

Заказ будет оплачен.

Стол будет окрашен.

Человек будет встречен.

Во всех случаях с предметом/объектом что-то произойдет, что изменит конечное состояние. Будет какой-то финал. Результат того что мы описываем. И на этом можно, условно закончить. Вот не было отметки, а теперь она есть. Стол был страшный, а теперь покрыт краской.

А вот если мы пытаемся сказать "звонок будет отвечен" то это нонсенс.
Потому что подразумевается продолжение действия. Ответ на звонок подразумевает процесс, разговор.
Звонок может быть сброшен. Может быть принят. Обработан, передан. Но не отвечен. Вот он звонил и вот изменил состояние. Больше не звонит.

"Отвечаю на телефонный звонок" - это вообще сократительный новояз. "Сниженный" стиль, как говорилось выше. "Я отвечаю человеку который позвонил мне на телефон."
"Зазвонил телефон, Сниму трубку и отвечу человеку". Но скорость общения и глубина проникновения технологий в нашу жизнь породили "ответь на звонок".